# Is there a way to add multiple jobs using HadoopJarStepConfig jarConfig = new HadoopJarStepConfig(HADOOP_JAR);

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr, hadoop2

I have written a AWS SWF workflow and the first action is to boot cluster and  run a mapreduce program. This action also has like 2 other mapreduce jars to be executed depending upon the first jar's output. I am using this to add the jars

```
    HadoopJarStepConfig jarConfig = new HadoopJarStepConfig(S3N_HADOOP_JAR);
    jarConfig.setArgs(ARGS_AS_LIST);
    HadoopJarStepConfig jarConfig1 = new HadoopJarStepConfig(S3N_HADOOP_JAR);
    jarConfig1.setArgs(ARGS_AS_LIST1);
    try {
        StepConfig enableDebugging = new StepConfig()
                .withName("Enable debugging")
                .withActionOnFailure("TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW")
                .withHadoopJarStep(new StepFactory().newEnableDebuggingStep());
        StepConfig runJar = new StepConfig(HADOOP_JAR, jarConfig);
        StepConfig runJar1 = new StepConfig(HADOOP_JAR, jarConfig1);
        request.setSteps(Arrays.asList(new StepConfig[]{enableDebugging, runJar, runJar1}));
        RunJobFlowResult result = emr.runJobFlow(request);
```

Is this the correct way to add multiple jars. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

request.withSteps(enableDebugging, runJar, runJar1);

Don't Use:

new StepConfig[]{enableDebugging, runJar, runJar1})); is wrong, you dont need a SpetConfig again here..

Comment: I have tried using this step to request to add another jar as part of the AddJob step in EMR. This works perfectly... Will also check what you have suggested.                        StepConfig runJar1 = new StepConfig(HADOOP_JAR, jarConfig1);
     AddJobFlowStepsRequest request2 = new AddJobFlowStepsRequest(jobFlowID).withSteps(runJar1);